# Телеграм бот выводит в сообщении с датой и числом символ "\."

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота на python, использую библиотеку aiogram. При отправке в сообщении даты или числа в формате 11.12.2020 или 345.23 или 11-12-2020 или 345,23 бот перед знаком точка или дефис ставит обратный слеш, получается вот так `11\.12\.2020` или `345\.23`.
Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

пример кода:

```
number = "%.2f" % float(number)  
text = code(f"Число: {number}")  
message.reply(text, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

[image: Вывод числа в телеграм]

Comment: что за функция `code` ?

Comment: Функция импортированная из aiogram, форматирует текст в виде кода

Answer (score 0):

Бот их экранирует, т.к. это не совсем обычные символы. То же самое должно происходить с `\`, `'`, `"` и еще много с какими. Попробуйте боту передавать дату в виде сырой строки `r'11.12.2020'`.

Comment: Дату и число я передаю именно в виде сырой строки, но все равно происходит экранирование.
Я уже нашел инфу здесь https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options, но пока все равно не понимаю, как это исправить.

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin у меня при таком коде норм отправляет дату.Можно подробнее как вы это делаете?
`@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    await message.reply(date_time, parse_mode='Markdown')`

Comment: Причем такая ошибка возникает только при использовании форматирования markdown

Comment: `number = "%.2f" % float(number)

text = code(r"Число: {number}")

message.reply(text, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)`

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin добавьте в вопрос минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Кнопка править под вопросом

Comment: @Sergey Govyazin в том источнике, который вы прислали есть такая фраза _can be escaped anywhere with a preceding '\' character, in which case it is treated as an ordinary character and not a part of the markup_. Как я понял - вам надо наоборот экранировать эти символы и не использовать сырые строки для данного типа форматирования.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло вместо markdown использовать разметку HTML, код получился такой:

```
number = "%.2f" % float(number)
text = f"<code> + Число: {number} + </code>")  
message.reply(text, parse_mode=ParseMode.NTML)
```